# UITableView is not displaying results correctly even though indexpath is being set correctly, any experts out there might be able to shed some light?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have taken just a very simple part of the code here to demonstrate just one of a couple of issues I am using UITabelView. Firstly when putting some test data into the table which is back by three arrays topicListOne, topicListTwo etc. So this part works fine but in the override where the cells are dequeued the section of the index path has reverted to zero. I have put un all appropriate overrides to handle the table i.e. return number of sections, return count of elements in each section etc. Has anyone seen anything strange like this before? I was using a similar approach with an earlier project and it all worked fine.

```
self.topicListOne.append("test1")
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        self.topicListOne.append("test2")
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
        self.topicListOne.append("test3")
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)], with: .automatic)
```

tried debugging and pretty much everything but whatever is happening is not obvious from the outside.

see the code in the question but also i added a few lines from the dequeue method and other overrides:

```
extension ViewControllerFive {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section
        {
        case 0:
            return topicListOne.count
        case 1:
            return topicListTwo.count
        case 2:
            return topicListThree.count
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let animation = AnimationFactory.makeSlideIn(duration: 0.5, delayFactor: 0.05)
        let animator = AnimatorManager(animation: animation)
        animator.animate(cell: cell, at: indexPath, in: tableView)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.labelOne.text = "Topic:"

        print("Index row: ", indexPath.row)
        print("Index sec: ", indexPath.section)

        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.labelTwo.text = topicListOne[indexPath.row]
        case 1:
            cell.labelTwo.text = topicListTwo[indexPath.row]
        case 2:
            cell.labelTwo.text = topicListThree[indexPath.row]
        default:
            fatalError()
        }

        cell.labelOne.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.labelOne.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.labelTwo.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.labelTwo.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        /*
         cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5)?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
         cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5)?.layer.masksToBounds = true
         */

        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        switch section
        {
        case 0:
            return "Trending News To Comment On"
        case 1:
            return "User Topics"
        case 2:
            return "Private Messages"
        case 3:
            return "Archived News Stories"
        default:
            return "Not Set"
        }
    }
```

no error messages per se but what appears in the view are the three test results all in the first section. There are other issues two in that i have a firebase listner also installed and these results dont seem to make it anywhere but maybe that should be a separate question. Any help from the ios swift experts out there much appreciated?

Comment: Have you connected the `tableView's dataSource` correctly?

Comment: In 'numberOfRowsInSection', check the count of all three arrays and see if all the arrays have some detail.

Comment: Your first 6 lines look suspicious. You are adding stuff to one array, but adding cells to three different sections.

Comment: Is DataSource and Delegate set to self?

Comment: sweeper, you are absolutely right duh stupid mistake, nice one thank you. PGDev thanks also another issue, Amini and Bhargav between all of you all im back up and running, eternally grateful thanks